# Assigning column value based on condition on another column in sql (teradata)

Tags: sql, teradata, self-join, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a table which has the following columns: `Date`, `AcctId`, `CustID`, `BackupID`, `Logins`, `Amount`. For a given Date, an `AcctID` can more than one `CustIDs`, but I want to assign a singular `CustID` to an `AcctID` based on the value of `Logins`.

---

***i.e.***:

If `Cust1` has more `Logins` than `Cust2` for the given Date and `AcctID` then `CustID` should have `Cust1` as value.

If `Cust1` logins = `Cust2` logins then `CustID` should have `BackupID` value.

---

I then want to add the `Amount` for the given `Date`, `AcctID`.

Can anybody help with logic? I tried self join but probably not thinking it the right way.

Comment: The tricky part is *If Cust1 logins = Cust2 logins then CustID should have BackupID value*. If *all* CustID per Date/AcctId show the same number of Logins, then use the BackupId? Is there a 1-1 relation between Acct_Id and BackupId?

Comment: And which Amount should be added in this case?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  And which backup id?  Is it always the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your rules using aggregation and window functions:

```
select acctid, date,
       (case when count(*) = 1 then min(custid)
             else min(backupid)
        end) as imputed_customer
from (select acctid, date, min(backupid) as backupid, custid,
             count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (partition by acctid, date order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by acctid, date
     ) ad
where seqnum = 1
group by acctid, date;
```

The subquery aggregates the data by `acctid`, `date`, and `custid`.  It also ranks the custids for a given acct/date combination.

The outer query then says:

- If there is only one maximum `custid`, then use that.
- Otherwise use the `backupid`.

Note that if there are multiple `backupid` on a given `acctid`/`date` combination, then an arbitrary one is used.

Comment: Thanks Linoff. This solved the problem. would sum(login) instead of count(*) be substituted for decision-based on login for each cust_id?